# Cannot deploy to firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, firebase-cli

Are you familiar with firebase and stripe?

Attempting to deploy the following script to functions will result in an error.

The error message says that there is a problem with this source.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});




const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const stripe = require("stripe")("stripe key here");


app.use(express.static("."));
app.use(express.json());

const calculateOrderAmount = items => {
  
  return 50;
};



app.use(cors);
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {


  const { items } = req.body;
  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "usd"
  });

  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Node server listening on port 4242!'));


exports.stripePayment4 = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Enter the command . The error message that appeared in the terminal afterwards was as follows
Error message that appears in the terminal after deploying

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        stripePayment(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:stripePayment"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

The error messages displayed in the firestore log are as follows

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"this my mail address"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/{myprojectid}/locations/us-central1/functions/stripePayment"}
```

Can anyone tell me the cause of the problem?

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting? Can you update your question to show it?

Comment: @PaulAsjes thanks for taking the time. to comment.　additional error messages have been uploaded. I hope you can check it.

Comment: Since v1.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions, `firebase-admin` should be initialized **without any parameters** within the Cloud Functions runtime: `admin.initializeApp();`.